# Pass array from jQuery AJAX to PHP and write the contents into a file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to parse one array and send it to a PHP file that will write the contents into a file.

This is the function

```
var label = a.text;
GetEl('emotion-label').innerHTML =  "I'm  " + a.text;

$.ajax({
    url: 'mehrabian_pad_subset with AB doubles 2d&3D.csv',
    success: function (data) {
        //parse your data
        //you can split into lines using data.split('\n') 
        //use regex functions to effectivley parse
        var new_label = GetEl('emotion-label').innerHTML;
        var label_custom = data.splitCSV();

        for (var i = 0; i < label_custom.length - 1; i++)
            if (label_custom[i][1] == a.text)
                $.post("JS/foo.php", {
                    data: label_custom[i]
                }, function (result) {
                    alert("test")
                }, "json");
    }
});
```

This is my php file

```
<?php
 $dir = '/var/www/devData/test';

 // create new directory with 777 permissions if it does not exist yet
 // owner will be the user/group the PHP script is run under
 if ( !file_exists($dir) ) {
  mkdir ($dir, 0777);
 }
 if (isset($_POST['data'])) {

         $stringData = $_POST['data'];
         $file = "/var/www/devData/test/ciao.txt"; 
         echo $stringData;
         echo "ciao";
         $fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
         fwrite($fh, $stringData);
         fclose($fh); 
 }


 ?>
```

Any one know how can I do this?

Comment: Would it work to encode the array using JSON, send it, then decode it on the receiving page? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php . You can probably encode it in a variety of other ways too.

Comment: So, does this work?  Not work?  What's the question here?

Comment: hey Rocket no doesn't work i can't read the data that i send trought the function

Comment: What does `console.log(label_custom)` say?  What is `data.splitCSV()`?

Comment: Make sure that it's A) Getting the file you specified with AJAX, a console.log of it would help you a lot here.  Next, if that part is working, maybe simplify it and pass the entire thing to the php script and see if it receives it and can write anything to the file at all.  If not make sure your php script can write to a file.  Also is there a reason you are not just posting the entire file at once headers and all?  Are you worried about hitting the data limit for a POST?

Comment: splitCSV is a parser :

String.prototype.splitCSV = function(sep) {
  
  var allTextLines = this.split(/\r\n|\n/);
  
  var headers = allTextLines[1].split(';');
  var lines = [];
   for (var i=1; i<allTextLines.length; i++) {
        var data = allTextLines[i].split(';');
  
  lines.push(data);
 }
   
 return lines;
};

Comment: the php can write on the file but i pass the all array i doens't write anythings.

Comment: Does `echo $stringData` print anything?

Comment: no anything doesn't enter in the if

Comment: I'll repeat then what was asked earlier what does console.log(label_custom) say?  It might not be getting the file at all.

Answer (score 0):

I solved easly i create a function that return a string like that, because i needed exactly that:)

```
function ArryToCsv(arr) {

  var csv = '';
  for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length-1 ; i++)
  csv +=   arr[i] + ';' ;
  csv += "\n";
  return csv;
};
```

I hope can help someone ;)